# Failed to start MySQL in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, sql

Installation process:

• sudo apt-get update
• sudo apt-get install mysql-server
• mysql_secure_installation (shows issue)

It shows socket related issues. I have done several uninstall/reinstall process but it still shows error while entering MySQL.

error 2002 (hy000) can't connect to local mysql server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

I need help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make sure MySQL is actively running? Open up your Process Monitor and look for mysqld, or go into command line and do "ps aux | grep mysqld".

If it's not running, "sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start"